What does it take to "ground out" a cat?
If I have a piece of fabric, like a shirt or the back of a chair, that's got static charge on it, I can typically run my hand over it once or twice and ground out the charge, and then it stops being staticky.  But I've recently noticed that my cat doesn't seem to follow the same rules.
There are times when I can be cuddling her, and pet her over and over, running my hand over her fur for 5 minutes or more, and still be getting little static sparks even after several minutes.
She's a fairly typical adult housecat with ordinary-length fur that is not excessively large or fluffy.  Where is all this static coming from, and how do I get rid of it?

have you measured the relative humidity in your house,if the air is too dry you will get static.where i live this is mostly a problem during winter.

I wonder if the clothes you're wearing is static-generating with the cat fur. Static can build up with friction and the 'right' pairs of materials. That or you accidentally adopted a picachu

@trondhansen That's quite possible.  I haven't noticed this phenomenon until fairly recently, as the weather's gotten colder.

you can take a look at this site: https://www.catster.com/lifestyle/why-is-my-cat-so-staticky/  you can do a goole search for static electricity cat to learn more about this.you can post an answer to your own question and get some extra points if you want to.
